# Counting documents returns empty array when done inside facet

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following MongoDB query:

```
Answer.aggregate([{
  $facet: {
    scoreRank: [{ $match: { 'quizzes.1._id': '5f19e5ed5611f647b70c44ef' } }, { $count: 'count' }]
  }
}]);
```

This should match 3 documents as running the same query without the `$count` would return:

```
scoreRank: [
{ _id: 12345, quizzes: [Array], __v: 2 },
{ _id: 54233, quizzes: [Array], __v: 2 },
{ _id: 2873, quizzes: [Array], __v: 2 },
]
```

Running with `$count` returns:

```
{ scoreRank: [] }
```

It should return:

```
{ scoreRank: [{ count: 3 }]}
```

Running the match and the count outside the `facet` would return the expected output but inside `facet` it returns nothing.

Comment: In general, you get a `{ scoreRank: [] }` when there are no matching documents to count.

Comment: Maybe it's: `'quizzes.1._id': ObjectId('5f19e5ed5611f647b70c44ef')` ?

Comment: @prasad_ yup but there are matching documents so I smell a bug here

Comment: @Valijon the `_id` is passed as function parameter so that's not the problem. The problem has to do with the `quizzes` array as querying other (non array) works returns the count.

Comment: Anyway, post a sample document showing the `quizzes` array.